# Stack overflow created by a cycle in code with singletons

Tags: java, stack-overflow, cycle, circular-dependency

I have two singleton classes, lets call them class `A` and class `B`.

The classes look like such.

```
class A
{
  private static A instance;

   private A(int timeout)
   {
     init();
   }

    public static A getInstance(int timeout)
    {
      if(instance == null)
      {
        instance = new A(timeout);
      }
      return instance;
    } 

    private void init()
    {
      new Monitor().sendMonitorStatus();
    }
}
```

and for class `B`

```
class B
{
private static B instance;

   private B(A a)
   {

   }

    public static B getInstance(A a)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new B(a);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then there is a class named `Monitor` as well that looks as such.

```
class Monitor
{
  public void sendMonitorStatus()
  {
    B.getinstance(A.getinstance(10));
  }
}
```

The problem as you can see, is that I get a `stackoverflow` since it keeps a cycle of a call to `B` then calling `A` which calls `B` which calls `A`..., is there anyway to solve this problem without a redesign or is the only way to solve this cycle causing this error to redesign how the classes work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an instance of `A`, you need to call `Monitor::sendMonitorStatus`. To call `Monitor::sendMonitorStatus`, you need an instance of `A`. You have a dependency cycle.

You need to redesign this. Exactly how – it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yup, was afraid there was no way around it. Well `A` populates a list of objects that are created in another class and `B` sends the message of these objects to another class, in a message protocol. I may need to add another class then it sounds like to get rid of this dependency on each other.